# Redirect calls to console.log() to standard output in Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

I'm using Jasmine via the jasmine-maven-plugin, and I would like to see console.log() messages in the Maven build output. Is there a way to achieve this?

If console.log() cannot be redirected, is there any other way to log from my tests so that they show up on the Maven build output?

I'm running these tests on Jenkins in a headless fashion, and would like a means to get some debug output from the tests.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990335/logging-from-grunt-contrib-jasmine

Answer (score 62):

Try

```
console.info('foo')
```

From the test javascripts.

Comment: Why .info rather than .log?

Comment: Oddly, with Jasmine 2.5, I had to do this instead of console.log. I have verbose on, but console.log does not show up (it shows log line + empty string), whereas console.info actually shows the log line + whatever I'm logging.

Comment: @user1338062 - so therefore your feedback from the downvotes is that you should have included the information that ezekial victor provided, if it had you may not have gotten the downvotes.

Answer (score 42):

### Jasmine 1.x

You can use:

```
jasmine.log("I've got a big log.");
```

### Jasmine 2+

Use `console.log` directly, as per [douglas-treadwell's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78181/douglas-treadwell) comment below.

Comment: That does not work for me; I don't see the output of `jasmine.log` anywhere in my terminal when running `mvn jasmine:test` (using plugin version 1.3.1.3, htmlunit 2.13)

Comment: @PavelLishin, it doesn't print to your console window, but it does print to the web runner.

Comment: This refers to Jasmine 1.x.  With Jasmine 2.0 just use console.log directly.

Answer (score 13):

If you are running in a node env. You could use

```
process.stdout.write("this will be send to the console");
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it **is not possible**.

I had to overwrite the console.log implementation in the spec loader. i.e *(using jQuery)*:

```
var console = {
    panel: $('body').append('<div>').css({position:'fixed', top:0, right:0,background:'transparent'}),
    log: function(m){
        this.panel.prepend('<div>'+m+'</div>');
    }       

};
        console.log('message 1');
        console.log('message 2');
```

​
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/kvRbN/) your have a functional example

Comment: IIUC, this prints console.log() messages to a <div>. What I want is to have it on the standard output of the Maven build instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is possible.  Just use console.log directly.  This doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Note that a `div` has a transparent background by default.

Answer (score 4):

If you're desperate for any output in a Terminal window so you can have data to review after the test has completed and the browser has closed, `console.error()` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `jasmine 2` via `guard` and `phantom js` and have found that standard `console.log` messages within tests are output to the jasmine spec runner's console just fine.

I've also found that `console.log` messages within the javascript code elements that I am testing do get written out to `stdout` but not `console.log` messages within the tests themselves.

Comment: console.log should work.  If you don't see your console.logs in the output, try adding more at earlier places in the call stack.  Most likely you have an error earlier that is preventing execution from reaching your console.log.

Comment: `console.error()` seems to work per my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41864171/916586).

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue using grunt/karma/jasmine (karma-jasmine 0.2.2) -

To go along with what Dave Sag said, I've found that all my `console.log` messages from the code I'm testing run fine, however nothing from my `describe() {}` and `it() {}` blocks log anything.

I *did* find that you can log from a `beforeEach() {}` block. At least it worked for me :

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.model = new blahModel();
  console.log('this.model = ', this.model);
});
```

*Note that* this only logs in the browser console and for some reason won't log in command line. Somewhat strange when the 
    console.log
statements from the tested code block do log in the command line. I've also found what seems to be a better approach for consistent logging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157999/output-jasmine-test-results-to-the-console).

UPDATE : I'm actually seeing the logging working for it blocks as well, I believe I had other errors that were preventing this.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to your project directory where you have your pom.xml. Run the following command in cmd.
mvn jasmine:bdd

2) You will get the localhost URL : localhost:8234  (just an example).

3) Run this URL in the browser. Now all your test cases gets executed.

4) Do the Inspect element of this page. In the browser console you will be able to see all the console.log() or console.error() traces.