# Capture console log of an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, console

Is there a way to capture the console outside of an iframe?

I'm working on an [online IDE](http://codemagic.aklp.gr) similar to jsFiddle and I wanted to give the users to option to at least read the results of the javascript console.

Comment: You can overwrite `console.log` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049996/redirect-calls-to-console-log-to-standard-output-in-jasmine-tests#11050414)

Comment: Won't that print the results in the iframe's content? I'd like to print the console logs in a div inside the iframe container's body

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is another solution if you don't want to append to HTML

```
var console = {
  __on : {},
  addEventListener : function (name, callback) {
    this.__on[name] = (this.__on[name] || []).concat(callback);
    return this;
  },
  dispatchEvent : function (name, value) {
    this.__on[name] = (this.__on[name] || []);
    for (var i = 0, n = this.__on[name].length; i < n; i++) {
      this.__on[name][i].call(this, value);
    }
    return this;
  },
  log: function () {
    var a = [];
    // For V8 optimization
    for (var i = 0, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
      a.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    this.dispatchEvent("log", a);
  }
};
```

Outside the iframe

```
iframe.contentWindow.console.addEventListener("log", function (value) {
  console.log.apply(null, value);
});
```

Answer (score 25):

If you want to print the log messages inside the window container's body, it is possible to declare the panel there:

```
var console = {
    panel: $(parent.document.body).append('<div>'),
    log: function(m){
        this.panel.prepend('<div>'+m+'</div>');
    }       
};
console.log('message');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it works as expected but could you please explain what this line does? `panel: $(parent.document.body).append('<div>'),`, I don't understand why we use the `.append('div')` part.

Comment: That's only for wrapping the messages into a single `div`. You can use `panel: $(parent.document.body)` too, but then you'll have each message directly as a child of the container's body.

Comment: Ya after a while i understood its purpose and modified it to fit my needs, thanks for taking the time to explain it to me.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Chrome DevTools. There is a Javascript Selector "Top" where you can select the source. The logs from that source will show up.

[image: Chrome DevTools Javascript Context Selector]

Comment: The answer is really offtopic though, the goal is to capture the logs in code and during runtime, this should run in everyone's machine, not just the developer's.

Comment: I was looking for this answer. Needed to reload the page for changes to take effect, for some reason. +1

Comment: The user is asking about how to capture the console output to print inside a div, not how to see the iframe console.