# Logging from grunt-contrib-jasmine

Tags: jasmine, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-contrib-jasmine to run my javascript specs. How do I write debug output to the console when running specs i.e. how do I get

```
console.log("something");
```

to show output in the console? I do find that I can get output by running:

```
 $ grunt jasmine --verbose
```

But this prints a lot of information that I'm not interested in. How can I just see the output from console.log ?

Comment: what were the other settings?                     display: 'short',
                    summary: true  - I cant seem to get it to log anything.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `console.info` instead of `console.log`

Comment: Don't forget `console.debug()`, `console.warn()`, and `console.error()`

Comment: Why?  Is `console.log` more for random logging that the test filters out purposely?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm getting the same result as @sten-muchow.  None of the console output (log, info or error) is appearing.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Turns out one needs the --debug grunt option rather than --verbose.  console.log, info and error all appear although there's no indication of which is which.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution but a work around (sort of).
Put in a `expect("something").toBe(null);` This will make jasmine to write out an error message like: `Expected 'something' to be null.` This way you can peek into objects (`expect(element).toBe(null);`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dump(variable)` or `console.log(variable)`.  [Source is the excellent Year of Moo.](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/09/advanced-testing-and-debugging-in-angularjs.html)