# Displaying Test Result Summary with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, protractor

I have an AngularJS app that I am using end-to-end testing on. This app relies on Protractor and Jasmine for testing. I'm running my tests via a Grunt task.

Does anyone know of a task or a way to display a summary of Protractor's test results in the command line? Currently, I have time-grunt to display a summary of how long each task took. I'd love to have the ability to show something like 'Ran [x] tests. [y] Succeeded. [z] Failed.'

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7158081/1112003 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a consoleReporter. It's a little more verbose, but it does give a summary at the end.

Using jasmine-reporters you can add several reporters. My favorite is the HtmlReporter that takes screenshots when the test fails. Below is an example of several reporters configured in the protractor.conf.js

```
onPrepare: function () {

    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('reports', true, true));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.ConsoleReporter());

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: 'reports/screenshots'   ,
        takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
    }));


},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tweak what you display in the console you can use [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter):

[image]